# Can I get jre package for AIX without installing java?

Tags: java, aix

I need jre package for AIX . Is it possible to download it from IBM site without installing it on AIX. Current state is when I untar the downloaded package the prodiced file is *.jre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to download from IBM's site different versions of JDK and JRE, both for 32 and 64 bit. Requires free registration.

The downloaded files are in 'backup format', they can be installed with 'installp', eg:

```
installp -aYd . Java71.sdk
```

Comment: Yes this is true. I found that they are backup files. In my case I should produce packages with **jce** in it not installing and all this repackaging is done with Ant tasks. For me **restore -qxvf $check_file_type** worked perfectly.